# How can I do a compose in wand?

Tags: python, wand

I'm trying to create a composition of an image with wand but I'm not able to find the right way to do so.

```
convert beijing_contrast.jpg  beijing_blurmap.jpg \
        -compose Blur -set option:compose:args 10 -composite \
        beijing_model.jpg
```

Can anyone help me make this ImageMagick command with wand?

Comment: Which wand? There is MagickWand and Python Wand. Please be more specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```py
with Image(filename='beijing_contrast.jpg') as src:
    with Image(filename='beijing_blurmap.jpg') as dst:
        src.composite(dst, operator='blur', arguments='10')
    src.save(filename='beijing_model.jpg')
```

The method [`Image.composite()`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/stable/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.composite) was updated in Python's Wand version 5.3 to include both `operator=` & `arguments=` parameters.